# Cursor hand on hovered links don't disappear with "cursor: none;"

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, document-body

I am trying to use my own cursor only for hovering on links. This is why I don't set `cursor: none` on the whole body. I am trying to get rid of the hand via JS. in the inspector the body cursor says its `cursor: none`, but the hand still shows over my cursor

```js
link.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    mouseCursor.classList.add("cursorHov");
    document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need JavaScript for this. You can just do it in CSS. Like this:

```
.link:hover {
    cursor: none;
}
```

For HTML:

```
<a href="whateverhref.com" class="link">Try hovering over this!</a>
```

Now, you just need to create links, and if you want them to have no cursor, then give it a class of link. Of course, you could change the class name. Also, just note that whateverhref.com isn't where you would really want to go, it's just a placeholder.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually pretty simple, and you don't need JavaScript for this. You can look for other things like :hover. For example, there is also :before, :after, and much more. And :hover isn't actually needed, but it's best to have it to understand. You could seriously just do the CSS selector without the :hover part.

Comment: I am using JS for the cursor to add and remove classes when hovering over and off clickable elements. I am having some elements that get a class added when hovered by the styling doesn't change! what do you mean by just use CSS selector without :hover?

Comment: You can just do this:
`
var a = document.getElementById("a");
a.style.cursor = "none";
`
Using this, you don't really need the hover part.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `cursor` property on `document.body` won't change it when it's hovering something else that uses a different cursor.

Don't use JavaScript for this, use CSS's [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act):

```css
.selector-for-your-link:hover {
    /* CSS for your cursor (whatever you currently have for your `.cursorHov` class) */
}
```